# After connecting to Point to Site VPN unable to to access local AD

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I have configured Point to Site connection that working great.

Unfortunately after connecting to the VPN I am unable to browse anything that is domain-joined on my local network. For example if I try to navigate to \192.168.1.2 or \192.168.1.2\sharename I get "Windows cannot access" error. The same happens to the AD shared printers.

I am able to ping the devices locally after the connection has been established and traceroute is showing me, that the server is visible locally. This is happening to all computers on my local AD, but also to a non-domain joined workstation.

The only workaround I found is this: Connect to the network shares before connecting to VPN. Then credentials are getting cached and I am able to access local resources. Also I can go to Windows Credentials manager and (even despite my computer is domain joined) add credentials for the local server with my own username/password and I can access all of the resources.

It almost feels like during the connection the credentials are getting passed onto the VPN instead of local network, and they never go back.

I need this to work as it is a part of a large solution for the number of customers, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Normal VPN works fine when I am connecting to other networks. Azure Point to Site VPN on the other hand is different and uses this azure VPn tool that seems to be resulting with the behaviour as above –  user106736 just now   edit

Answer (score 1):

The recommended by Microsoft engineer solution is to disable credential manager. After this users are authenticated by Kerberos authentication.

You have to apply the flowing reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]

"disabledomaincreds"=dword:00000001
```

And restart your computer.